# How to improve performance in Angular 2 with a multi-dimensional List with actions?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

Hello i am developing an application with Angular2. I recieve via an api a multi-dimensional list that I must display in an html table.

Here is the simplified version of the json that I receive from the api:

```
 {
  "events": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": 0,
      "sub_events": [
        {
          "id": 0,
          "name": 0,
          "actions": [
            {
              "id": 0,
              "name": 0
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to isolate the components when displaying like this:

**ListComponent**:

```
<event-view  [event]='event' *ngFor="let event of events"></event-view>
```

**EventComponent: (event-view selector)**

```
<div>
<h1>{{event.id}} {{event.name}}</h1>
<table>
  <tr subevent-view [subEvent]='subEvent' *ngFor="let subEvent of event.sub_events"></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**SubEventComponent: (subevent-view selector)**

```
<td>{{subEvent.id}}</td>
<td>{{subEvent.name}}</td>
<td>
  <event-action  [action]='action' *ngFor="let action of subEvent.actions"></event-action>
</td>
```

**EventActionComponent: (event-action selector)**

```
<button (click)='....' >{{action.name}}</button>
```

All my components use changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush

I would like that when I click on an action Angular 2 does not recheck the whole list but only the clicked button.

For now Angular does a check on the list + one check on all events + one on all subevents + one on all actions ...

I tried using ChangeDetectorRef.detach but it does not change anything.

My root list **events** is created with ImmutableJS.

Is there a way to tell angular to check only one child component without re-checking the whole tree?

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: I ve created the Plunker. You can see check in log console.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aVMD4IMg6bxwcMvhZ271?p=preview

thx

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to prevent these checks. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36178526/change-detection-appears-to-occur-on-click-event-regardless-of-detached-setting

Comment: :( Ouch.... On a browser there is no problem but with an old smartphone and nativescript these checks make the application unusable. ;( ;( ;(
Thx for your time

Comment: I can't imagine why these checks would make it unusable, they aren't doing anything.

Comment: The action object is updated by the onclick and so initalList !== listAfterClick and initialRow !== rowAfterClick

Comment: You should look how changeDetection works. It's tree based and comes from top to bottom. While you can optimise subtree by not running its changeDetection you can't do the same for uptree. i.e. AppComponent changeDetection will always run and in your example so does all parent of `<event-action>`.

Comment: Well this isn't totally true, you can still detach the changeDetection from your component and do it all by yourself. But this is meant to be exceptional use, not sure your use case justify it. There is an example on the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html) (under detach()). But it's not working anymore, there is an [issue about it](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8597).